# Allure Report - Environment not displaying Environment.properties/environment.xml

Tags: allure

Trying to set up the environment table in the Allure report, tried to create environment.properties and the environment.xml, but its not generating the environment field. I see in the environment.json file, its empty.
Any idea?
Thanks.

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-allure-environment</id>
                        <phase>validate </phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>environment.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create the `environment.properties` from the code during the test?